# GetHashCode return different values

Tags: c#, wcf

If I run this code on `.Net Framework 4.5.2` console app:

```cs
var test = "test";
var testHashCode = test.GetHashCode();
```

value of `testHashCode` is: `-871206010`

When I run the same code on `.Net Framework 4.5.2` wcf service, value of `testHashCode` is `-354185609`. Why there is a difference?

Comment: hash codes are not guaranteed to be the same across different application domains as it mentions in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

`GetHashCode()` is not intended to be a reliable permanent hash function; all that is required, intended and documented is that *inside the same program execution*, it should (if correctly implemented) return the same output for inputs that equate as true (see also: footnote). For different processes (or even different app-domains in the same process), the output can be different. This can even be desirable, to prevent some kinds of dictionary saturation attacks based on predictable hashing behaviour. The rules can *certainly* change between framework versions, operating systems, etc - this allows, for example, for performance improvements to the implementation.

So basically: for what you seem to want: use something like SHA or some other stable hashing algorith, *not* `GetHashCode()`.

(footnote: it doesn't say anything about returning different output for inputs that equate as false)